# inkscape2tikz missing arrowheads

Tags: tikz-pgf, inkscape

`inkscape2tikz` doesn't seem to cope very well with arrowheads. Is there a way around this? Maybe my picture is also already too complicated for this extension to work out-of-the-box and I should choose a different method of export, however the typical PDF + TeX file with text does not work for me at all, not much is kept left in the resulting PDF, just a couple of lines. How would you go about exporting a figure with some coloured text and subscripts?

[image: original]

[image: inkscape2tikz]

Comment: After you export the code you can edit it to insert the arrows and to adjust the nodes with texts.

Comment: That is always an option, but given how messy the generated code is, it is very inconvinient. I tried installing the `texText` extension, but haven't managed yet, it is not very user-friendly.